# bootstrap card overlaps on top of each other on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, material-design, col

So i have one "flipping card" and another bootstrap 4 card side by side like this: (I have edited the image to hide text)
[image: on desktop mode]

However when this is tested on target mobile screen using chrome's dev consolde, The 2nd Card overlaps the flipping card and completely covers it. like this:
[image: on mobile screen]
I have put the code inside the container, row and col-md-* like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
      ....
      <div class="col-md-8">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For full refrence, here is my full html and css code:
html:

```
    <!-- start of third block -->

    <div class="thirdblock">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card-container">

                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <div class="cover">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="user">
                                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/...jpg" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="main">
                                            <h3 class="name">.</h3>
                                            <p class="profession">.</p>

                                            <p class="">..

                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Flip
                                                </div>
                                            </p>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div> <!-- end front panel -->
                                <div class="back">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="main">
                                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                            <p class="lead">

                                                .</p>

                                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                                <br>

                                            <div class="stats-container">
                                                <div class="stats">
                                                    <h4>100+</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Followers
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="stats">
                                                    <h4>10+</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Following
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="stats">
                                                    <h4>100+</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Projects
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div> <!-- end back panel -->
                            </div> <!-- end card -->

                        </div> <!-- end card-container -->

                    </div> <!-- end col-md-4 -->




                    <div class="col-md-8">

                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                                <p class="lead">
                                </p>

                                <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" src="images/....png" />

                                <br>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div><!-- end row -->



            </div> <!-- end container -->

    </div>

    <!-- end third block -->
```

And the huge css code:

```
.thirdblock {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
    background-image: url("../images/image.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.card {
    font-family: 'Arima Madurai', Verdana;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #444444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

/*Flipping Card Code*/


/*Flip Card Starts*/
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
    outline: 0 !important;
}

/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.card-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 900px;
    -moz-perspective: 900px;
    -o-perspective: 900px;
    perspective: 900px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

/* flip the pane when hovered */
.card-container:not(.manual-flip):hover .card,
.card-container.hover.manual-flip .card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.card-container.static:hover .card,
.card-container.static.hover .card {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.card {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .5s;
    transition: transform .5s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front,
.back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    z-index: 3;
}

.back .btn-simple {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
}

/*        Style       */




.card-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.card .cover {
    height: 105px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.card .cover img {
    width: 100%;
}

.card .user {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    margin: -55px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
}

.card .user img {

    width: 100%;
}

.card .content {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}

.card .content .main {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.card .back .content .main {
    height: 100%;
}

.card .name {
    font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.card h5 {
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.card .profession {
    color: #999999;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card .fofooter-toter {
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .footer-t .social-links {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card .footer-t .social-links a {
    margin: 0 7px;
}

.card .footer-t .btn-simple {
    margin-top: -6px;
}

.card .header {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 90px;
}

.card .motto {
    font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .stats-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.card .stats {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .stats:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.card .stats:last-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

.card .stats h4 {
    font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card .stats p {
    color: #777777;
}
```

Can someone please help me as in what am i messing up?

Answer (score 1):

just add fixed `height` for your `.card` class, because of position absolute on `.front` and `.back` classes, card class won't take any height.

```
.card{
height:362px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the CSS for class
.front,.back

```
 /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: 0; */
```

Comment: what? its a flipping card, that ruins it completly